# django user_passes_test decorator is_superuser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Initially i was restricting the permission for all user with the help of is_superuser flag,and i used `@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)` decorator.Now i am not using is_superuser flag and instead i created a field in UserProfile model called is_admin_user and allowing the permission depend on the flag in UserProfile model.

If is_admin_user flag is set,he can access the application settings page,otherwise they can't access the settings page.While creating profile using is_admin_user flag,the default django is_superuser flag is set to false.Since i am using the decorator i am not able to access the settings page.If i click settings page it redirect to login page.

1.Is it possible to create any other custom thing for is_admin_user.

2.If i comment this line `@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)` ,able to move to settings page.

Need suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.userprofile.is_admin_user)
```

You may need to change `userprofile` to your profile `related_name`

Comment: +1 for providing me an answer.Is it possible to set this decorator for two fields in UserProfile model like this,1.@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.userprofile.is_admin_user) and 2.@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.userprofile.is_primary_user).Both are boolean field both values are not present at all time.I tried with both lines one after the other,the time it is not giving access to settings page.If i click settings it takes me to login page.Any suggestion.

Comment: You want @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.userprofile.is_admin_user or u.userprofile.is_primary_user)?